# Facebook "Test Apps" don't copy open graph settings

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm taking advantage of Facebook's "Test App" functionality. After creating a test app, it looks like it didn't copy over any of my Open Graph stories, action types or object types. Therefore, none of my open graph functionality works in my test environment.

Do I really have to copy all that over manually, or did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

From Facebook FAQ, looks like not...I'm in the same boat...ugh!

**My production app's settings have changed. Is there an easy way push that setting to all my test apps?**

Not at present, although we hope to add this feature in the future. For now, you'll need to change settings in each test app manually. Alternatively you could create a new test app who's settings will be copied from the production app at create-time.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/test-apps

Comment: Unfortunately, my settings (namely OG objects) were NOT copied from the production app at create-time.

Comment: It doesn't look like they do and need be recreated manually for each type (for me it's x4) + sample stories will need to be regenerated for each app type to preview them.